# Why does Paket try to bring in hundreds of dependencies for CliWrap?

Tags: dependencies, nuget, paket

I'm using the latest .NET Core SDK on Ubuntu (`dotnet-sdk-2.1` version 2.1.403) and I'm trying to install [CliWrap](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/CliWrap) on an empty project.

(In fact it's not even a project, it's a directory with `.fsx` files that load the dependencies using the `#r` F# magic.)

Here is what Paket wants to do:

```
$ echo 'source https://nuget.org/api/v2' > paket.dependencies
$ paket.exe add --no-install CliWrap
Paket version 5.181.1
Adding CliWrap to /tmp/test/paket.dependencies into group Main
Resolving packages for group Main:
 - CliWrap 2.0.1
 - Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.5
 - Microsoft.VisualBasic 10.3.0
 - System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow 4.9.0
 - System.Net.Http 4.3.3
 - runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.3
 - System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource 4.5.1
 - System.Net.Security 4.3.2
 - Microsoft.CSharp 4.5.0
 - System.Buffers 4.5.0
 - System.ComponentModel 4.3.0
 - System.ComponentModel.Annotations 4.5.0
 - System.Diagnostics.Process 4.3.0
 - System.Dynamic.Runtime 4.3.0
 - System.Globalization.Extensions 4.3.0
 - System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher 4.3.0
 - System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles 4.3.0
 - System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream 4.3.0
 - System.Linq.Expressions 4.3.0
 - System.Linq.Parallel 4.3.0
 - System.Linq.Queryable 4.3.0
 - System.Net.NameResolution 4.3.0
 - System.Net.Requests 4.3.0
 - System.Net.WebHeaderCollection 4.3.0
 - System.Numerics.Vectors 4.5.0
 - System.Reflection.DispatchProxy 4.5.1
 - System.Resources.Reader 4.3.0
 - System.Runtime.Loader 4.3.0
 - System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms 4.3.1
 - System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding 4.3.0
 - System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives 4.3.0
 - System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates 4.3.2
 - System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions 4.5.1
 - System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel 4.3.0
 - System.Threading.Thread 4.3.0
 - System.Threading.ThreadPool 4.3.0
 - runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography 4.3.4
 - Libuv 1.10.0
 - NETStandard.Library 2.0.3
 - Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native 1.7.0
 - System.Reflection.Metadata 1.6.0
 - Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 2.9.0
 - Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic 2.9.0
 - Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostPolicy 2.1.5
 - Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR 2.0.8
 - Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 2.1.1
 - Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 2.9.0
 - System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 4.5.2
 - System.Reflection.TypeExtensions 4.5.1
 - runtime.debian.8-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography 4.3.4
 - runtime.debian.9-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography 4.3.4
 - runtime.fedora.23-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography 4.3.4
 - runtime.fedora.24-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography 4.3.4
 - runtime.fedora.27-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography 4.3.4
 - runtime.fedora.28-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography 4.3.4
 - runtime.opensuse.13.2-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography 4.3.4
 - runtime.opensuse.42.1-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography 4.3.4
 - runtime.opensuse.42.3-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography 4.3.4
 - runtime.osx.10.10-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography 4.3.4
 - runtime.rhel.7-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography 4.3.4
 - runtime.ubuntu.14.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography 4.3.4
 - runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography 4.3.4
 - runtime.ubuntu.16.10-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography 4.3.4
 - runtime.ubuntu.18.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography 4.3.4
 - runtime.debian.8-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.3
 - runtime.debian.9-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.3
 - runtime.fedora.23-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.3
 - runtime.fedora.24-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.3
 - runtime.fedora.27-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.3
 - runtime.fedora.28-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.3
 - runtime.opensuse.13.2-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.3
 - runtime.opensuse.42.1-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.3
 - runtime.opensuse.42.3-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.3
 - runtime.osx.10.10-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.3
 - runtime.rhel.7-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.3
 - runtime.ubuntu.14.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.3
 - runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.3
 - runtime.ubuntu.16.10-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.3
 - runtime.ubuntu.18.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.3
 - runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.Apple 4.3.1
 - System.AppContext 4.3.0
 - System.Console 4.3.1
 - System.Diagnostics.Tools 4.3.0
 - System.IO.Compression 4.3.0
 - System.IO.Compression.ZipFile 4.3.0
 - System.Net.Sockets 4.3.0
 - System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation 4.3.0
 - System.Text.RegularExpressions 4.3.0
 - System.Threading.Timer 4.3.0
 - System.Xml.ReaderWriter 4.3.1
 - System.Xml.XDocument 4.3.0
 - System.Reflection 4.3.0
 - Microsoft.Win32.Registry 4.5.0
 - System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives 4.3.0
 - System.Text.Encoding.Extensions 4.3.0
 - System.Linq 4.3.0
 - System.ObjectModel 4.3.0
 - System.Reflection.Emit 4.3.0
 - System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration 4.3.0
 - System.Reflection.Primitives 4.3.0
 - System.Threading.Overlapped 4.3.0
 - System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight 4.3.0
 - System.Reflection.Extensions 4.3.0
 - runtime.native.System 4.3.1
 - runtime.native.System.Net.Http 4.3.1
 - System.Collections 4.3.0
 - System.Diagnostics.Debug 4.3.0
 - System.Diagnostics.Tracing 4.3.0
 - System.Globalization 4.3.0
 - System.IO 4.3.0
 - System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0
 - System.Net.Primitives 4.3.0
 - System.Resources.ResourceManager 4.3.0
 - System.Runtime 4.3.0
 - System.Runtime.Extensions 4.3.0
 - System.Runtime.Handles 4.3.0
 - System.Runtime.InteropServices 4.3.0
 - System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.5.0
 - System.Text.Encoding 4.3.0
 - System.Threading 4.3.0
 - System.Threading.Tasks 4.3.0
 - System.Security.Principal.Windows 4.5.1
 - Microsoft.Win32.Primitives 4.3.0
 - runtime.native.System.Net.Security 4.3.1
 - System.Collections.Concurrent 4.3.0
 - System.Security.Claims 4.3.0
 - System.Security.Principal 4.3.0
 - System.Runtime.Numerics 4.3.0
 - System.Globalization.Calendars 4.3.0
 - System.Security.Cryptography.Cng 4.5.0
 - System.Security.Cryptography.Csp 4.3.0
 - Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostResolver 2.1.5
 - Microsoft.NETCore.Jit 2.0.8
 - System.Collections.Immutable 1.5.0
 - runtime.osx.10.10-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.Apple 4.3.1
 - System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo 4.3.0
 - System.Diagnostics.StackTrace 4.3.0
 - System.Text.Encoding.CodePages 4.5.0
 - System.ValueTuple 4.5.0
 - System.Xml.XmlDocument 4.3.0
 - System.Xml.XPath.XDocument 4.3.0
 - runtime.native.System.IO.Compression 4.3.2
 - Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers 2.6.2
 - Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetAppHost 2.1.5
 - Microsoft.NETCore.Targets 2.1.0
 - System.Xml.XPath 4.3.0
Locked version resolution written to /tmp/test/paket.lock
Dependencies files saved to /tmp/test/paket.dependencies
Performance:
 - Resolver: 23 seconds (1 runs)
    - Runtime: 2 seconds
    - Blocked (retrieving package details): 12 seconds (69 times)
    - Blocked (retrieving package versions): 8 seconds (9 times)
    - Not Blocked (retrieving package details): 77 times
    - Not Blocked (retrieving package versions): 137 times
 - Average Request Time: 136 milliseconds
 - Number of Requests: 166
 - Runtime: 24 seconds
```

That's bonkers!

Installing it manually with Nuget works without a problem:

```
$ nuget.exe install CliWrap -ExcludeVersion -OutputDirectory packages
Feeds used:
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Installing package 'CliWrap' to 'packages'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/cliwrap/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/cliwrap/index.json 287ms


Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'CliWrap.2.0.1' with respect to project 'packages', targeting 'Any,Version=v0.0'
Gathering dependency information took 21.99 ms
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'CliWrap.2.0.1' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'CliWrap.2.0.1'
Resolved actions to install package 'CliWrap.2.0.1'
Retrieving package 'CliWrap 2.0.1' from 'nuget.org'.
Adding package 'CliWrap.2.0.1' to folder '/tmp/test/packages'
Added package 'CliWrap.2.0.1' to folder '/tmp/test/packages'
Successfully installed 'CliWrap 2.0.1' to packages
Executing nuget actions took 54.2 ms
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `storage: none` option in your `paket.dependencies` file to disable the `packages` folder and use the global NuGet cache instead.

For more information see [here](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/dependencies-file.html#Disable-packages-folder).

Comment: I tried it and while the files no longer shows up in ./packages this still brings in a lot of dependencies. Still bonkers imho.